# SoundCloud API for iOS not sharing on facebook

Tags: ios, facebook, share, soundcloud

I'm using SCShareViewController from SoundCloud API in my project (iOS 7.0) so that the user can share your audio on SoundCloud AND on Facebook through the SoundCloud UI.
The upload in SoundCloud is working perfectly! But the share on facebook is not working =/

Does anyone can help me with this?

Is it necessary for me to create an app on facebook? Or does it already use SoundCloud's instead?

**EDIT:**

Here is my code:

```
NSURL *trackURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:trackPath];

SCShareViewController *shareViewController;
shareViewController = [SCShareViewController shareViewControllerWithFileURL:trackURL
                                                          completionHandler:^(NSDictionary *trackInfo, NSError *error){

      if (SC_CANCELED(error)) {
          NSLog(@"Canceled!");
      } else if (error) {
          NSLog(@"Ooops, something went wrong: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
      } else {
          NSLog(@"Uploaded track: %@", trackInfo);
      }

  }];

[self presentModalViewController:shareViewController animated:YES];
```